When to use platform Threads over Virtual Threads
Java 21 introduced the lightweight virtual threads API. Every tutorial I encountered describes them as "as, or more scaleable" then the common platform threads.
I understand that virtual threads run on top of platform threads, but just from the user perspective I want to know if there are now any reasons left to directly use platform threads, for example for ExecutorServices.
I'm not interested in opions but concrete examples like insertion in the debate between Linked- and ArrayList.

platform for cpu intensive and virtual for io

The JEP-444 with Using virtual threads vs. platform threads tries to explain this. Do you intend to ask something beyond it? Can you edit the question and explain how?

Virtual threads might be better for simple tasks,longer tasks(waiting),uses less memory compared to platform threads,where one shouldn't worry about handling thread lifecycle(less control kind Af) as much I understood , for heavy and more controlled tasks platform threads would be better.

tl;dr

Choose virtual threads unless making heavy use of synchronized, native code,  or CPU-bound code.
As needed, throttle your virtual threads with Semaphore (or some such).

Details
Virtual threads are very efficient with both memory and CPU. Common computer hardware can support over a million virtual threads.
Virtual threads should be your default choice rather than platform threads.
Virtual threads are contraindicated in any of these situations:

Your task has long-running or frequently-called code that uses synchronized.
Your task has long-running or frequently-called native code (Foreign Functions, JNI, etc.).
Your task is CPU-bound, without blocking, meaning no logging, no file I/O, no database access, no sockets, no network or Web Services calls. For example, video encoding/decoding.

As of Java 23, if your task involves any of those situations, use platform threads.
(Occasional brief use of either synchronized or native code in a virtual thread is not a problem. Just avoid deadlocks, etc.)
The Project Loom team is hard at work trying to remove that first limitation involving synchronized. See JEP 491: Synchronize Virtual Threads without Pinning.  Early-access builds available now. The team very much wants trial usage and feedback as the changes go deep into the JVM.
Of course, “cheap” threads may perform expensive tasks. If your task involves a scarce or heavy resource, throttle your many virtual threads to make limited usage.
Throttling is commonly performed with Semaphore. Use try-finally to never lose a permit.
static final Semphore limitAccessToFooSemaphore = new Semaphore ( 7 ) ;  // Specify number of permits. Or use `1` for a binary semaphore. 

// Your task code, a `Runnable` or `Callable` implementation.
… do some inexpensive work
try
{
    limitAccessToFooSemaphore.acquire() ;  // Blocks until a permit becomes available.
    … do expensive work 
}
finally
{
    limitAccessToFooSemaphore.release() ;  // Return the permit to the semaphore’s pool. 
}
… do more inexpensive work

Before virtual threads, some programmers got into the bad habit of using limited-size thread pools as a way of indirectly throttling access to scarce resources or limit expensive work. Better to manage those directly and explicitly via Semaphore or some such.

For more details, see the excellent video presentations at YouTube by Alan Bateman, Ron Pressler, or José Paumard.
See especially the latest by Alan Bateman where he explains that virtual threads are not “pixie dust”, correcting some misconceptions that have risen within the community.
And read JEP 444!

what do you mean with “cheap” threads ?

@pochopsp  As I said: "Virtual threads are very efficient with both memory and CPU.". Read JEP 444.

@matt … while semaphores that are restricted to the values 0 and 1 (or locked/unlocked, unavailable/available) are called binary semaphores … https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)

@matt Yes, that is why I said: “use 1 for a binary semaphore.”

I don't understand. If you use 1 for a permit and something calls release, you have 2. Nothing assures it is binary. It's irrelevant so Ill delete my comments, I have an actual question though. Why use a platform thread? It seems that the cases you provide the virtual thread just behaves as a platform thread. They're not really examples for why you would use a platform thread.

You write: "Better to manage those directly and explicitly via Semaphore or some such" but you don't explain why that is better? I am a bit unsure that this is a universal truth. For instance, in a fixed size thread pool, if any processing step is slow, it will automatically slow down previous processing steps, resulting in an automatic backpressure that limits the number of pending tasks. In contrast, if each task runs in its own virtual thread, new threads may be created faster than they can complete, exhausting available memory rather than slowing down the process that overtasks our system.

@meriton Virtual threads take very little memory by default. And virtual threads release memory as well, in contrast to platform threads. So, generally you can proceed with a million threads as long as they throttle on their expensive sections of code. Alternatively, you could throttle the creation of tasks and/or throttle task submission to an executor service. The point of my Answer is to make your throttling intentions obvious and explicit to those reading your code, rather than burying your intent within same mysteriously limited number of threads in a pool of platform threads.

@meriton Using a limited-size thread pool as an indirect way to throttle your tasks or limit access to expensive resources was never a good approach.  Virtual threads does not change that; virtual threads just bring the issue into focus.

Yes, virtual threads have very little memory overhead. But their local variables, and the objects referenced by them, do use memory, and depending on where exactly the thread gets held up by a semaphore, that working memory can be significant. Unlimited thread pools require unlimited memory. Virtual threads don't change that, they just make the problem easier to miss. And part of the problem is the new and misleading narrative that virtual threads are so "cheap" we needn't limit their number.

It's good that your answer calls attention to the need for throttling. I just wish it were more thorough in its discussion of why we need to: It mentions the need for throttling outgoing requests lest we overload the other system, but it doesn't discuss the need for throttling incoming requests lest our system be overloaded by others.

What does it mean to be "Using platform threads"
This should not mean "new Thread(...)".
Lets create an example. I am going to crawl a website, each request is going to require some IO. This io will consume a thread, but not use the CPU heavily.
executor.submit( () ->{
    List<Runnable> next = crawlWebsite();
    next.forEach( executor::submit );
});

crawWebsite is just a method that downloads the website parses it and finds the next URLs to visit.
If crawlWebsite gets stuck on the http request, then the os is free to prioritize another thread. If your executor has a fixed number of threads then they can all be stuck on IO? All of your processors are free, but you cannot start a new task because all of your threads are blocking.
Why not just create more threads?
Threads are "expensive". Some thread pools are built on the principle of creating more threads, like Executors.newCachedThreadPool. That works great, unless you are creating thousands of threads. Then the overhead becomes prohibitive.
That is what virtual threads are to address. Cheap actions that might block for a long time without consuming much cpu. Then you can submit the to Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTask. The threads are created used and forgotten. It gets around the finite threadpool problem, and it gets around the overhead of creating platform threads.

It will not help if your tasks are CPU bound.
Virtual threads can become pinned for certain tasks (esp synchronized block)

I'm not really convinced you shouldn't just use virtual threads instead of platform threads. One instance would be to limit the number of threads you use for a set of tasks.

The gist of it is programming style as explained here JEP-444.

You can use OS Threads, but then the OS Threads will be the bottleneck of your highly concurrent code.
You can use asynchronous code (like React and other frameworks do) but then you're burdened with a lot of callbacks and a more complicated debugging scenario.
Or you can use virtual threads and have 1 thread per request and pretend the OS can handle it.

The caveat is that it works well when your tasks are mostly I/O bound. Such as in a web application where you do a little bit of processing and then call the database (and wait).
For CPU intensive tasks (like a parallel in-memory sorting algorithm) this is not the right approach.
A final bonus: you don't need to pool virtual threads. In fact, you shouldn't. So that also simplifies your code model.

TL;DR
Virtual threads are intended for transient (short-lived/ephemeral) and I/O-bound loads while platform threads are used for long-running CPU-bound tasks.
Virtual threads have less startup/shutdown overhead and are more efficient when I/O bound, but they aren't as good at scheduling CPU-bound tasks.
Platform threads
Before JDK 19, all that was available was platform threads. They were simply a Java wrapper to an OS-level thread. You had a chunk of code that could run concurrently, but you had to hand it off to the system. This involved slow syscalls and allocations, alongside reliance on the OS's scheduler. It wasn't a huge deal for big tasks that stay running, but it wasn't great for transient tasks or blocking I/O operations, as the system still had to perform a context switch only to find the thread blocked.
Additionally, some operating systems limit the amount of threads a program can have. This causes issues for large server-type software with a lot of concurrency.
Virtual threads
This is why virtual threads were introduced. They are "threads" that are really run on top of a pool of OS-level threads, kept alive by the VM. This cuts down on context switches and expensive allocations, as well as limiting the thread count.
For example, if you wanted to thread a basic image filter, virtual threads would work well (if the filter was very lightweight). With platform threads, the VM would have to make a thread (with all of the syscalls), add some handles, run it for under 100 milliseconds, then destroy it (with more costly syscalls). Virtual threads allow the VM to quickly pick one out of a pool and get it running.
This is also beneficial for blocking I/O. If a thread is running and is waiting on a lock or a buffer, the VM can just skip it without wasting time on context switches, and even reassign the underlying OS thread to another task.
Problems
The main problem with virtual threads is that they're based on a pool of platform threads. This isn't normally an issue if used well, but if you have too many tasks, it becomes a problem.
If you have a pool of 12 platform threads supporting 12 virtual threads, the JVM doesn't really need to get involved. However, if you add 1 more virtual thread, the JVM has to do its own scheduling.
If you use virtual threads properly, the JVM would remove a thread blocked on I/O or a lock to run another. Additionally, short CPU-heavy tasks wouldn't cause too much of an issue as the OS thread wouldn't be locked up for too long, and the overhead dies with the thread.
However, if they're all long-running CPU-bound tasks, you run into problems. The JVM's scheduler is going to be less efficient (especially since the OS is also scheduling the underlying OS threads with everything else). In the end, you get roughly double the overhead from 2 schedulers, and need to deal with a lot of context switching.
This is why platform threads are still used. If you want to thread a long file transfer or mass hashing operation, you shouldn't take up virtual thread time if you're not going to benefit from it.
Additionally, platform threads have more memory and stack space for complex operations, while virtual threads are limited in those regards (as they are meant to be for small tasks).
Finally, reassigning threads like this might cause some issues with caching (see thread pinning).
Effectively using virtual and platform threads
To effectively use virtual threads:

Use proper locks instead of spinning loops
Exit as soon as you can
Prefer blocking I/O

Likewise, for platform threads:

Keep them alive for as long as you'll need them
Constantly do stuff, don't leave it waiting too much
Use non-blocking/async I/O and do other tasks in the meantime

Conclusion
Virtual threads are very useful, but not universally so. Use virtual threads for small or "sparse" (mostly I/O blocked) tasks, and use platform threads for heavy/long tasks, where the overhead is less important and the scheduling more of an issue.

What are transient loads?

By "transient load", I specifically mean short-lived loads (like a single JDBC query). I'll clarify more in the answer.

This isn't AI, but I see how that could be a bad example.

Spinning loops are bad, but I mainly used it to highlight the fact that the JVM can reschedule time away from locked threads. Also, someone new to concurrency (who, you know, might be looking for the difference between platform and virtual threads) might be using loops, even though it's bad. I'm capping it here so this comment section doesn't get longer. Downvote if you like, edit the answer or provide constructive criticism, but I'm done.

The statements “The JVM's scheduler is going to be less efficient…” and “you get roughly double the overhead from 2 schedulers” are made out of thin air. The current state of affairs is that there is no JVM scheduler, hence, it can’t be less efficient. If you run a CPU bound task on a virtual thread, it will simply run on the underlying carrier thread, only left to the scheduling of the operating system. The JVM does not interfere, as preemptive task switching has not been implemented for virtual threads (yet).
